# Collapse strings before empty cell in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, paste, rvest

I want to scrape all the content which has the class "content-text__container" inside the tag "p". While scraping, some of the sentences are in the row bellow. I want to collapse, so the paragraph is inside just one cell. For doing that I need to collapse the content before the empty cell in the "checagem" column.

```
url <- "https://g1.globo.com/fato-ou-fake/noticia/2018/10/05/veja-o-que-e-fato-ou-fake-nas-falas-dos-presidenciaveis-no-debate-da-globo.ghtml"

texto <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("p.content-text__container") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_trim() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  `colnames<-`("checagem") %>%
  mutate(checagem = toupper(checagem),
         checagem = rm_accent(checagem)) %>%
  mutate(rotulo = ifelse(str_detect(checagem, "VEJA O PORQUE:"), 
                         checagem, NA))
```

For example, this means that the content in the row 121, 122 e 123 (image below) should be in just one row.
[image: Print screen of the example]

Answer (score 0):

Not as familiar with webscraping. But if I understand your problem let's assume you have:

```
dat <- data.frame(checogem = c("A", "A1", "3", "", "G", "GS", "", "F1", "F2", "F3"))
```

Then your goal is to collapse all the values between blank values together.

One method is:

```
dat %>% mutate(gr = cumsum(checogem == "")) %>% group_by(gr) %>% summarise(new_checogem = paste(checogem, collapse = "+")) %>% ungroup()
```

using `paste(..., collapse = "+")` means that I want to space between each row to be a `+`. You can also use a blank (`""`) or a space (`" "`).

Comment: I am not sure what your intention was, but at least here it didn't work.

Comment: My understanding is that you wanted everything between blank rows of `checogem` as one row/cell. What did not work about it?